# «Пятиэтажый» или «пятиэтажий»?

Tags: словообразование, гласные

В песне одной хорошей группы отыскалась вот такая строчка:

*— Я не знаю твой язык **пятиэтажый***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удивляться не надо, там лирический герой в тексте — хрущёвка-пятиэтажка. Вопрос: правильно ли писать «пятиэтажый» через «ы» после шипящего? И если нет, то как доказать обратное?

Comment: Когда я учился в школе, было распространено строжайшее правило: _жи-ши пиши с буквой "и"!_

Comment: Ага, а когда начинаешь учиться в вузе, то оказывается, что строжайшее правило предполагает ударную позицию, безударное положение, кучу оговорок и порцию исключений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В тексте песни группы «Комсомольск» — Пятиэтажечка feat. Варвара Краминова слово «пятиэтажий» через «и».

> Пятиэтажечка, вот сидим
>  Сигаретный дым, батарейный чан
>  Я не
> знаю твой язык **пятиэтажий**
>  Что ты тихо бурчишь
>  Скрипишь,
> свистишь мне о чём-то
>  О чём-то важном
>
> [[on-hit.ru](https://on-hit.ru/texts/komsomolsk-pjatijetazhechka/)]

Где вы нашли текст с «ы»? Такого текста нигде найти не удаётся, есть только с «и».

> В сочетаниях «Жи» и «Ши» после шипящих согласных всегда пишется буква
> «И». Это правило орфографии русского языка относится к традиционным -
> его нужно запомнить.
> …
> **Исключения**
> В данном правиле исключений нет. Буква "Ы" может быть использована
> после "Ш" или "Ж" только в именах собственных. Например, есть город
> Шымкент в Казахстане.
> [[infoogle.ru](http://infoogle.ru/zhi_shi_pishi_s_bukvoj_i.html)]

«Пятиэтажий» в данном случае не является именем собственным и должно писаться с «и».

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! На вопрос «откуда» отвечаю: в Apple Music. Причём судя по тому, что тексты песен стали там доступны одновременно с релизом нового альбома, расшифровки оригиналов вероятнее всего предоставляли непосредственно музыканты. On-hit.ru, Genius.com и прочая при всём уважении всё-таки суть вторичные ресурсы, которые занимаются подобной расшифровкой самостоятельно, на слух и с собственными неизбежными огрехами.

Comment: По поводу самого слова — злополучная «ы» находится в безударной позиции в окончании, а в этом случае правила рекомендуют «делать проверку с помощью ударения или путём грамматического анализа». В грамматический анализ я не очень, а для проверки ударением в голову лезут только этажѝ. Уж не знаю, насколько это уместно. Потому и спросил.

Comment: @Andrey Bessemer Я с вами согласен, насчёт того, что в Apple Music, скорей всего, текст давали сами музыканты, и он более оригинальный. С другой стороны, поскольку это всё-таки музыканты, а не лингвисты, они могли в своём тексте ошибиться. Насчёт проверки ударением, мне кажется, это больше относится к выбору, например, «а» или «о», чем «и» или «ы» в «жи/ши», всё-таки для «жи/ши» существует особое правило. Может попробовать спросить у самих музыкантов? У них есть страничка во Вконтакте: [komsomolskband](https://vk.com/komsomolskband).

Comment: @Andrey Bessemer Я ещё подумал, тут в стихах используется необычная рифма: *Пятиэтажечка, вот сидим — Сигаретн**ый** дым, батарейн**ый** чан — Я не знаю твой язык пятиэтаж**ый** — Что ты тихо бурчишь —
Скрипишь, свистишь мне о чём-то — О чём-то ва**ж**ном*

Comment: @Andrey Bessemer *Сигаретный дым, батарейный чан — Я не знаю твой язык пятиэтажый — Что ты тихо бурч**ишь** —
Скрип**ишь**, свист**ишь** мне о чём-то — О чём-то важном*

Comment: @Andrey Bessemer Они рифмуют, я так понял, концы слов внутри текста. И, возможно, из соображения подбора рифмы к «сигаретн**ый**» и «батарейн**ый**» они написали «пятиэтаж**ый**». Возможно, они подбирали рифму, когда писали текст, и не учли, что звучит «-ж[ы]й», но пишется «-жий». Я думаю, это просто орфографическая ошибка музыкантов.

Comment: Вряд ли виноваты _авторы_ - скорее, это небрежность того, кому поручили видеомонтаж (на федеральных каналах и не такая грамматика встречается). Гугл находит минимум два сайта с полным текстом, и там нет этой ошибки. Ближайший "проверочный" аналог - _говяжий_ :)

Comment: Не-не-не, я уже связался с группой — тексты в Apple Music заливали как раз они, и опечатку ребята признали. Точнее, не стали спорить с «и» в окончании.

Comment: @Alex_ander Видеомонтаж — монтаж видео — соединение частей видео между собой нужным образом. Никакого отношения к созданию содержимого видео не имеет. Видеомонтажёр может соединить части видео в нужной последовательности, может что-то обрезать, что-то вставить повторно, но он не отвечает за текст на видео. И где вы тут видите видео?

Comment: @Andrey Bessemer Хорошо, что вы связались с ними непосредственно — всё прояснилось. Теперь понятно, откуда в Apple Music берутся слова, и что это ошибка. Кстати, ребята молодцы, что признали ошибку, поступок достойный уважения. А то бывает так, что люди начинают любой ценой доказывать, что они правы, как им кажется, чтоб не потерять лицо.

Comment: @Eagle То, что вы понимаете под видеомонтажом (аналог склеивания фрагментов кинопленки в нужной последовательности) называется _линейным (видео-)монтажом_. Это простейшая операция в процессе, понимаемом под видеомонтажом (или _нелинейным монтажом_ - так говорят, когда хотят напр. акцентировать возможности программы-видеоредактора). К видеомонтажу в современном понимании относится и наложение перманентных титров на видеоряд.

Comment: @Andrey Bessemer Это не так. Линейный монтаж был, когда работали с плёнкой, тогда кусочки плёнки склеивали один за другим последовательно, или кусочки фильма записывали один за другим на другую плёнку. При линейном монтаже надо проматывать всю плёнку, чтоб добраться до нужного момента. Компьютерные программы позволят осуществлять нелинейный монтаж, т.е. доступ возможен напрямую к редактированию любого момента фильма, в любом порядке. Это два вида видеомонтажа. Видеомонтаж не имеет отношения к содержанию текста в кадре.

Comment: @Andrey Bessemer Вы могли бы поставить галочку, что ответ принят. Я думаю, он помог вам найти решение.

Comment: @Eagle Без проблем :)

Comment: @Andrey Bessemer Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

1. **Как правильно?**

Слово «пятиэтажий» выглядит **необычно** по сравнению со словом «пятиэтажный», что-то с ним не так. Вот и появляются сомнения с его орфографией. В чем же его **необычность?**

Похоже оно на притяжательное прилагательное, например: черепаший –  черепашьего, где ИЙ – это суффикс. По аналоги вспоминает **притяжательный** суффикс ЫН после Ц: *лисицын.* После Ц и в окончаниях пишется Ы: куцый.

А если слово необычное, то как его писать?

2. Решение: выбираем букву И после Ж

Слова «пятиэтажий» нет в словаре (это авторский неологизм), но можно самим выбрать для него правильную форму письма. Буква Ы в окончании  прилагательного может писаться только **после Ц** (смуглолицый, куцый), но после шипящих используется только И – пятиэтажий.  Здесь исключений нет, действует общее правило. Сравнить: рыжий, темнокожий.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

В ЧЕМ ОСОБЕННОСТЬ ШИПЯЩИХ И Ц (информация для тех, кто не любит всё запоминать, но любит всё понимать)

1. **Причина орфограммы**

Шипящие и Ц составляют группу согласных, **непарных** по твердости/мягкости: Ж, Ш, Ц – всегда твердые, Ч, Щ – всегда мягкие.  Твёрдость или мягкость согласных обозначается с помощью парных гласных букв А – Я, О – Ё, У – Ю, Э – Е, Ы – И, если за согласным следует гласный звук.

После всегда твёрдых  Ж, Ш, Ц и всегда мягких Ч, Щ гласный звук может быть  обозначен **любой из парных гласных букв**, что и является причиной орфограммы. Таким образом, появляется определенная **степень свободы**, с которой неизвестно что делать.

2. **Общий принцип решения**

Общий принцип решения орфограммы   заключается в том, что для шипящих и Ц действует **единое правило выбора гласных**, при этом твердость или мягкость шипящих и Ц **не обозначается** на письме. . Для обозначения гласных после шипящих и Ц в основном используются **буквы первого ряда,** как основного (А, О, У, Е, И);  употребление букв второго ряда требует обоснования (речь идет о буквах Ё и Ы).

3. **Немного истории**

При выборе этого решения учитывалось **традиционное** написание слов. Звуки Ж, Ш, Ц когда-то были **мягкими**, а потом отвердели. В 13 веке произошло отвердение звуков  Ж и Ш, но написание слов сохранилось прежним. В орфографии это сказалось на традиционном **«мягком»** написании И в орфограмме ЖИ-ШИ.

Со звуком Ц дело обстояло сложнее. Звук Ц в древнерусском языке был мягким, его отвердение началось в 14-15 веках  и к 17 веку **отразилось на письме**: отцы, улицы, бледнолицый, лисицын, а также цыган, цыпленок, на цыпочках. Однако в словах, пришедших в русский язык позже (цирк, циркуль), а также в корне слова на ИЯ (станция, милиция) пишется буква И.

4. **А это современность**

Итак, в современной орфографии Ы пишется в 4-х словах-исключениях  (цыган, цыплёнок, цыц, на цыпочках), в суффиксе прилагательных ЫН: (лисицын, царицын),  в окончаниях существительных и прилагательных (бойцы, страницы, молодцы, смуглолицый).

В  остальных случаях звук Ы после Ц обозначается **буквой первого ряда И**.   Современное употребление буквы Ы в какой-то мере отличает русскую лексику от заимствованной.

Отметим, что написание И в таких словах, как ***циновка, цирюльник, цифра, панцирь***, было установлено только Правилами 1956 года, а в  проекте реформы 2001 года рекомендовалось вовсе исключить все написания Ы после Ц: циган, огурци. Также интересно, что до реформы 1918 года на месте современной буквы И после Ц писалась буква I (И десятеричное):  медицiна, станцiя.